# Unison with davfs

Tags: synchronization, webdav, unison

I'm trying to do bidirectional sync of the local directory and cloud storage with WebDAV access.

I mounted cloud storage with `davfs` as local partition and tried to sync it with the local directory via `unison` with the following profile:

```
batch = true
fastcheck = true
follow = Path *
perms = 0
repeat = watch
root = /home/user/local/
root = /mnt/webdav/
...
```

But every time after mounting partition first sync takes about 10 hours and following syncs takes seconds.
In my case, 90% of the files are pictures. Is it possible to force option `fastcheck` for some files extensions ( e.g. *.jpg)?

Or maybe there are other ways to speed up synchronisation?

Comment: Is Unison recreating new archive files every time you mount the partition and run the first sync?

Comment: Looks like it uses one archive file. I deleted all previous archives (to be sure). Started sync - the new archive was created. Then I stopped unison, remounted partition and started unison again - it used already existing archive file.